# Rows to Columns using Sql Query

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot

hi i have a table with columns as

```
              Cost     Rate

              Repair   12
              Repair   223
              Wear     1000    
              Wear     666
              Fuel     500
              Repair   600
              Fuel     450
              Wear     400
```

Now i want this data as

```
             Repair    Wear   Fuel
               825     2066    950
```

Using Sql Query

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
select sum(case when cost = 'Repair' then rate else null end) as Repair
, sum(case when cost = 'Wear' then rate else null end) as Wear
, sum(case when cost = 'Fuel' then rate else null end) as Fuel 
from CostRateTable
```

Comment: Use WHEN instead of WHERE within the CASE syntax.  And terminate a CASE with END or END CASE.

Comment: Ah, I was writing off the bat and didn't syntax checked. I'll fix it up, Cheers.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid hard-coding column names? When someone adds a row named "Brakes" the query must be rewritten? The PIVOT approach is more generic but it is not as simple.

Comment: @Muxecoid you can always dynamically generate your query, based on your databases' flavour of metadata. It would be a case of creating a domain-data table with your 'Brakes' as a sibling entry for 'Fuel', under a super category of say 'Car Costs'; then generate a query by looping through all 'Car Costs' nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The "rotation" you want (making rows into columns) can be obtained with SQL Server's [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're looking for a way to do *Dynamic Pivoting* or *Dynamic Cross-Tabs*.

Check these articles:

- [SQLServer: Dynamic Cross-Tab](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3657506/SQLServer-Dynamic-Cross-Tab.htm)
- [Dynamic Cross-Tabs/Pivot Tables](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-cross-tabs-pivot-tables)
- [Crosstab Pivot-table Workbench](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/crosstab-pivot-table-workbench/)
- [SQL Dynamic CrossTab Stored Procedure](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/articles/5120.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GROUP BY`](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-sql-tutorial/) to combine results when using an aggregate function like `SUM()`.

```
SELECT Cost, SUM(Rate) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Cost
```

This will return the results inverted from what you requested, but that shouldn't be a big deal I hope.

```
Cost     SUM(Rate)
---      ---
Repair   825
Wear     2066
Fuel     950
```

Answer (score 0):

select cost,sum(rate) from tablename group by cost

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple Crosstab query. There is a wizard in the Access Queries window that will walk you through creating one.  Just click the New Query button and select the Crosstab Query Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy query using the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.  If you have a few values that are known to be converted to columns, then you can use a static version:

```
create table yourtable
(
  cost varchar(10),
  rate int
);

insert into yourtable values
('Repair', 12),
('Repair', 223),
('Wear', 1000),
('Wear', 666),
('Fuel', 500),
('Repair', 600),
('Fuel', 450),
('Wear', 400);

select *
from
(
  select cost, rate
  from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
  sum(rate)
  for cost in ([Repair], [Wear], [Fuel])
) p;
```

If you have an unknown number of values, then you can use dynamic SQL to create a dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(cost) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
              select cost, rate
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(rate)
                for cost in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa3b4/3).  Both will produce the same results.