# Query(ms access) to Turn rows to column

Tags: database, ms-access

I have table with column in ms Access

```
       Cost
      Repair
      Maintainance
      Wear
      Fuel
```

i want this rows as

```
    Repair  Maintainace Wear Fuel
```

as separate column as shown above

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052248/converting-rows-to-column; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047498/rows-to-columns-using-sql-query

Comment: Those questions are both duplicates of each other, and neither one has the correct answer in it.

Comment: In all fairness, there are answers in the questions, but the people posing the question haven't been seen since asking the questions, so they can't have accepted any of the answers. If they are anything to go by, this may occur again with this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a Crosstab query. There is a wizard in the Access Queries window that will walk you through creating one.  Just click the New Query button and select the Crosstab Query Wizard.